# Auto focus needs refresh to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the first text box to have focus, however this doesn't seems to work exactly as expected, when the page loads for the first time, the focus appears once(on the correct text box) and goes away immediately. However when I refresh the page then it works as expected. The script below is what I have used to set the focus

```js
$(function () { $('#userEmailAddress').focus(); });
```

This is a peace C# code for the text box itself

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = 1, @id = "userEmailAddress" })
```

Comment: I can only guess since you didn't provide more code, but try to add a setTimeout() with like 10ms delay around your focus method and tell me what happened.

Comment: why dont you just add the `autofocus` in your `HTML helper` ? `new { @class = "form-control", @tabindex = 1, @id = "userEmailAddress" , @autofocus="autofocus"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think if you use autofocus is better :

`<input type="text" name="some_field" autofocus>`

and this input will take focus as soon the page load.

Hope it helps.